# Checkbox value not changing Angular 2 with local reference

Tags: javascript, angular

How to check is checkbx is checked or not

> it is always showing true

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" (keyup)="0" #grade value="true">
    {{grade.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing `value="true"` and adding `[(ngModel)]="grade.value"`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai no i am asking for angular 2 with local reference

Comment: @Ashu, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai NP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is correct with

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" #grade (change)="0">
  {{grade.checked}}
</div>
```

Comment: why `(change)="0"`?

Comment: @Maximus local refrence need some method to update its value for the view

Comment: so what does zero mean?

Comment: 0 means nothing but this method will execute on each changes

Comment: if it means nothing, why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

**.html**

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox (change)="onChange(checkbox.checked)"></mat-checkbox>
```

**.ts**

```
onChange(checked: boolean) {
  console.log(checked)
}
```